# How to pass HTTP Request to web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

IDE: VS 2010

I have a requirement in that I have to consume service from HTTP request (Without adding service reference in client project.) I have followed lots of tutorials, but in all I am getting error 505, while making

```
System.Net.HttpWebResponse resp =(System.Net.HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
```

Here is one of the sample code which I have used

```
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8090/MyService.asmx");
        //req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("127.0.0.1", true);
        //req.Htt("POST /_22YardzWebService.asmx/ReceiveXMLByContent HTTP/1.1");
        //builder.Append("Host: localhost");
        req.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
        //req.ContentLength = 4096;

        //Add these, as we're doing a POST
        //req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        req.Method = "POST";
        //We need to count how many bytes we're sending. Post'ed Faked Forms should be name=value&
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Parameters);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;


        //System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
         //Push it out there

        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        //os.Close();

        System.Net.HttpWebResponse resp =(System.Net.HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
        if (resp == null) return null;
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

code source :http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx

Web method is working when called from service reference,

sample web Mathod:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string Test()
    {

        return "hello";
    }
```

Comment: `void` means you won't return anything. So the return "Hello" is never returned to the client.

Comment: yea, I modified the code for sample reason, but this is not the issue for error 505..

Comment: HTTP Error 505 means HTTP version not supported. Make sure the HTTP version your client requests is the same the server can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample method does not return data.

Here is my example and working.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
         public string HelloWorldNew(string data1,string data2)
         {
          return "Hello World" + data1 + data2;
         } 
    }
```

Console Application Code. ( Simple HelloWorld)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:60395/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld");
        request.Method = "POST";
        var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Console Application Code. ( Simple HelloWorldNew)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string data = "data1=user1&data2=user2";
        byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:60395/Service1.asmx/HelloWorldNew");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();            
        newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string dataReturn = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wao, I tried 5 hours, and this code solved issue. thanks