# Why I am getting error 500 when passing XML Data to Web service

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

In this post

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519558/how-to-pass-http-request-to-web-service?noredirect=1#comment43469479_27519558
```

as answered by dotnetstep, this is working when I pass simple string text, but when i changed this code to pass xml data I am getting error 500. please tell me what wrong I am doing

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xmlTempData = LoadXML(@"C:\Users\Yogesh\Desktop\receivedPath\File_12.xml");
        string data = "data1="+xmlTempData+"&data2=user2"; //Modified text
        byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:52995/_MyWebService.asmx/HelloWorldNew");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream(); //here getting error 500
        newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string dataReturn = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

if I change this line to

```
string data = "data1=hello&data2=user2"; //this is working 

string data = "data1=<tag1>text</tag1>&data2=user2"; //this is returning error 500.
```

Comment: Error 500 is a server error. You can't troubleshoot this from the client without the actual server error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896213/passing-xml-document-as-an-parameter-to-web-services-in-c-sharp

Comment: but this is accepting simple string, not xml data string <tag1>hello</tag1>

Comment: Imagine that you are developer of this web service. So you can easily write few lines of code which will accept string but will cause exception when processing XML. So are you sure that web service accepts XML and your XML is well formed for the service?